# this pointer notation of 2d array does not work as expected?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

2d array declared by me.

```
static char daytab[2][13] =  {
    {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
    {0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
 };
```

I want address location of the element [1][5].

When I use the statement    `char *p = &daytab[1][5];` it works but when I use pointer notation  `char *p  = &(*(*daytab+1)+5);` then it shows error?

Comment: Read about pointers and arrays

Comment: There is no "pointer notation" for arrays. If an array was the same as a pointer, why wouldn't it be called "pointer", but is called "array"? See [ask] and provide a [mcve]. The line shown shoud generate a compiler warning. First enable warnings and resolve all errors **and warnings**, then ask - except for the error(s)/warning(s) you have a **specific** question about.

Comment: Please note that technically, there are no "2d arrays", there are only arrays of arrays. The distinction becomes important when we talk about types, especially element types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a+i)`, not `*a+i`.

Comment: @SwapnilMishra Glad to be of help. The next step on Stackoverflow would be to *accept* the answer that was most helpful. You do this by clicking the check mark under the arrows. This will earn you some credits.